How do I create an email body using a textbox in HTML?
I have a form with a text box element in it.
I want to be able to use the textbox the same way it would work in an email body.
Where you can have:

HTML code in the body
In line Images

So something like this should be doable:

Text here
Image Here
Text here
HTML here
Text Here

I am unfortunately only limited to 1 HTML file so CSS and Scripting has to be done in one file along with the HTML body. Since I am using this as a front end that we'll be attaching to a separate system.
So actually something like this textbox I am using to post this question with a formatting header would work as well.
Any help is appreciated
Thank you!
Right now I am just working on a simple one.
It sort of works and allows drag and drop of images but the drag and drop portion is separate.
Also, it does not allow HTML elements like this text box would.
Sample below:


    function allowDrop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
      ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.src);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = data;
      img.style.width = "100px";
      img.style.height = "100px";
      ev.target.appendChild(img);
      document.getElementById("description").focus();
      document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, " " + img.outerHTML + " ");
      document.getElementById("htmlInput").value = document.getElementById("description").innerHTML;
    }

    function getHTML() {
      document.getElementById("htmlInput").value = document.getElementById("description").innerHTML;
    }
    #description {
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 10px;
      min-height: 200px;
    }

    #dropArea {
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 10px;
      min-height: 100px;
      width: 200px;
    }
  <div id="description" contenteditable="true"></div>
  <input type="hidden" id="htmlInput" name="htmlInput">
  <button onclick="getHTML()">Submit</button>
  <br><br>
  <div id="dropArea" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)"></div>




Building a rich text editor is one of the most challenging tasks in web development. Google it and read some of the many articles about it.
